# Problems setting up samba and connect with windows, "You can't access this shared folder..."

Tags: server, samba

I have tried multiple guides on the internet trying to solve this problem that I have.
I have installed samba on my Ubuntu server 18.04.1. I added the shared folder with the following settings:

```
#my shared folders
[ Backup ]
 comment = Backup
 path = /media/Backup
 browseable = yes
 read only = no
 valid users = MyUserName
```

However, when I try to connect from Windows I don't get prompt to enter my login-info. I just get the error that states:
"You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network."

I tried adding these lines to my config:

```
#Globala settings
[global]
admin users = MyUserName
security = user
```

When I did that, instead of getting the error message I now just get the message that my windows computer can't connect to the address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove/comment out the following in the `smb.conf` config file:

```
map to guest = Bad User
```

This is because Windows attempts to login with the current users windows credentials as default. If that doesn't work, it gets mapped as guest on the server side, something that the latest Windows versions do not allow.